# Plotly figures using State only pick up data from "newest" State

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard where the end user (technically able person) can add data sources ("simulated" below by the csv files) and the dashboard will generate the relevant graph, so 3 data sources, 3 graphs and so on.

The code below "works for the last data source", uploading screenshots keeps failing, but the code below should run fine if you have all the requirements installed and you'll see the graph for the first 2 sources is blank, while the third one works as desired.

Here's a simplified version of what I am doing

````
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, callback, Output, Input, State
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from io import StringIO
import csv
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"


df0_str = '''"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"
1,3,4,2,5,6,5,2,1,3,4,6
2,4,5,3,6,7,6,3,2,4,5,7
3,5,6,4,7,8,7,4,3,5,6,8
4,6,7,5,8,9,8,5,4,6,7,9
5,7,8,6,9,10,9,6,5,7,8,10
6,8,9,7,10,11,10,7,6,8,9,11
7,9,10,8,11,12,11,8,7,9,10,12
8,10,11,9,12,13,12,9,8,10,11,13
9,11,12,10,13,14,13,10,9,11,12,14
10,12,13,11,14,15,14,11,10,12,13,15
11,13,14,12,15,16,15,12,11,13,14,16
12,14,15,13,16,17,16,13,12,14,15,17
13,15,16,14,17,18,17,14,13,15,16,18
14,16,17,15,18,19,18,15,14,16,17,19
15,17,18,16,19,20,19,16,15,17,18,20
16,18,19,17,20,21,20,17,16,18,19,21
17,19,20,18,21,22,21,18,17,19,20,22'''

df1_str = '''"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"
10,13,14,13,10,9,11,12,14,1,3,4
13,14,12,15,16,15,12,11,13,2,4,5
14,15,13,16,17,16,13,12,14,3,5,6
15,16,14,17,18,17,14,13,15,4,6,7
16,17,15,18,19,18,15,14,16,5,7,8
17,18,16,19,20,19,16,15,17,6,8,9
18,19,17,20,21,20,17,16,18,7,9,10
19,20,18,21,22,21,18,17,19,8,10,11
13,9,11,2,5,6,5,2,1,3,4,6
14,16,12,3,6,7,6,3,2,4,5,7
15,17,13,4,7,8,7,4,3,5,6,8
16,18,14,5,8,9,8,5,4,6,7,9
17,19,15,6,9,10,9,6,5,7,8,10
18,20,16,7,10,11,10,7,6,8,9,11
19,21,17,8,11,12,11,8,7,9,10,12
20,22,,9,12,13,12,9,8,10,11,13'''

df_list = []
dfstr_list = [df0_str, df1_str]
for df_str in dfstr_list:
    csvStringIO = StringIO(df_str)
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep=","))
my_children = []
for num, df in enumerate(df_list):
    my_children.append(html.H3(
        children=f"name of {num}",
    ))
    my_children.append(dcc.Store(id=f'data_{num}', data=df.to_dict()))
    my_children.append(dcc.Input(id=f'range_{num}', type='number', value=12, min=1, step=1))
    my_children.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(id=f'fig_{num}', )))

# for child in my_children:
#     print(child)

@callback(
    Output(f'fig_{num}', 'figure'),
    Input(f'range_{num}', 'value'),
    State(f'data_{num}', 'data')
)
def update_graph(range_selected, data):
    df_for_figure = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).iloc[-range_selected:, :]
    fig = df_for_figure.plot()
    return fig

app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=my_children
)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    ```


What am I missing? How do I get all three graphs render according to the data provided?
````

Comment: `num` only exist in the 1st for loop so you should get an error when the f-strings are evaluated, or the code is wrongly indented in your question. But anyway, this approach will lead you to the same issue as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75607567/2529954), the answer provided should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that post @EricLavault. I am having a look and struggling, but maybe it clicks soon. Regarding num exising in the first for loop, it  has not caused any problem with the f-strings (the second for loop was a 'debugging' leftover) and the indentation is as intended, but leaves me wondering, what made you think the indentation is wrong?

Comment: Because you are using `num` in the f-strings, which is defined and incremented in the for loop (I thought you intent was to declare one callback per num/df). The problem you have is that `num` in the f-strings evaluates to the last value from the loop, and thus the callback only works for the last graph.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured it out thanks to @EricLavault's pointer.

Using pattern matching callback selectors was indeed the way to go.

The relevant code changes appear here:

```
for num, df in enumerate(df_list):
    my_children.append(html.H3(
        children=f"name of {num}",
    ))
    my_children.append(dcc.Store(id={'type': 'data_store', 'index': num}, data=df.to_dict()))
    my_children.append(dcc.Input(id={'type': 'time_range', 'index': num}, type='number', value=12, min=1, step=1))
    my_children.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(id={'type': 'fig', 'index': num}, )))

@callback(
    Output({'type': 'fig', 'index': MATCH}, 'figure'),
    Input({'type': 'time_range', 'index': MATCH}, 'value'),
    State({'type': 'data_store', 'index': MATCH}, 'data')
)
def update_graph(range_selected, data):
    df_for_figure = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).iloc[-range_selected:, :]
    fig = df_for_figure.plot()
    return fig
```

Thank you again, Eric!